# Passing a Variable as a Type WITHOUT using Reflection: 'myvar' is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, types, casting

I've got a simple method that deserializes an xml string to a type that is specified.

```
public static class TextUtility
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That's all good.  Where I'm having trouble is in calling this method.  The process looks like this:

```
public interface IMessageReceived
{
    string MessageBodyAsXML { get; set; }
    string MessageType { get; set; }
}

public class MessageReceived : IMessageReceived
{...}

List<MessageReceived> messageList = new List<MessageReceived>();
```

Then, in the worker class that is processing the messages, we loop over all the messages received.  Inside that loop, we loop over a list of potential message types.

```
foreach (MessageReceived message in messageList)
{
    foreach (var processor in processors)
    {
        if (processor.TypeToProcess.Name == message.MessageType)
        {
             // Now Create an instance of 'processor' from message.MessageBodyAsXML
        }
    }
}
```

I tries this:

```
object messageObject = TextUtility.DeserializeMessage<object>(message.MessageBodyAsXML);
```

And it kinda works, but the generic 'object' causes problems down stream.  I need to be more tightly coupled. I can do this:

```
Type type = processor.GetType();
```

And that *does* populate 'type' with the correct type. But then obviously I can't do this:

```
type messageObject = TextUtility.DeserializeMessage<type>(message.MessageBodyAsXML);
```

I am trying hard to avoid a long if/then for each type. Open to ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method)

Comment: There *are* ways to switch from reflection (type-based) code into static (generic-based) code, but it is rarely worth it; the most obvious solution here would be: don't use generics at this point. Do you need that?

Comment: Avoiding generics is exactly what I'm trying to figure out how to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously for such dynamic purposes where you don't know the type at compile-time you will need to provide an overload of your `Deserialize` method:

```
public static object Deserialize(Type targetType, string xml)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok, this is making sense.  I may start a new thread on how to write the overloaded method, if I need help with that. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the implementation would depend on the specific XML serializer you are using but if you are using the standard `XmlSerializer` you could specify the target type when instantiating it: `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(targetType)`.

Comment: Wow, isn't passing a type as a normal parameter kind of defeating the purpose of Type Parameters? But this is probably Microsoft's fault, not yours.